# Can I skip some variables in boost serialization?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-serialization

I have `Players` class and it has some variables

```
class Players
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar>
    void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned)
    {
        ar &username &password;
    }

public:
    std::string username = "", password = "", email = "";
};
```

I just want to serialize username and password. I dont want to add email too. I'm getting error after trying to deserialize it.

Comment: See the boost example about [splitting up save/load operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#splitting).

Comment: Please add the error messages to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct.
Remember that you cannot deserialize an archive that you created with an old version of the serialization routines.

If that is the case, as a very primitive workaround you can do this below, or learn how to deal with archive **versions**.

```
    template <class Ar>
    void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned)
    {
        std::string dummy_email = "";
        ar &username &password & dummy_email;
    }
```

Comment: the thing is i dont want to add email to it like i need to keep the default value

Comment: @cmdocmd Then do that. Just, don't expect it to be compatible with earlier saved archives. You need [versioing](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning) for that